# Collapsing AppBar title empty until it starts collapsing

Tags: java, android

The issue is, as the title states, that when the appbar is fully visible the title isn't, and when it starts collapsing, the title appears (images below)

[image]

So here's what it looks like when the AppBar is fully visible

[image: So here's what it looks like when the AppBar is fully and partly visible]

And here's when I've started scrolling down

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?android:attr/windowBackground">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                    android:outlineProvider="paddedBounds"
                    android:elevation="100dp"
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <fragment
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the layout for my activity

This happens regardless of fragments, so I won't be providing them for now.

```
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_settings, R.id.navigation_updates)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

And this is the way I set the AppBar.

So my goal is just to have the title always be visible. Another bug I noticed that might be related - the title, even when visible, doesn't change regardless of fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to set

```
app:titleEnabled="false"
```

for the CollapsingToolbarLayout and it worked afterwards